# HP LoadRunner's Controller

Tags: testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have to test a set of functions (online functions, batches and web services) for a company and I'm using LoadRunner. 
I had no problem creating the scripts with Vugen, but I have a question regarding the parameters file. 
Let's say I have 10 scripts, set 10 vusers into the controller (so 1 vuser for each script) and 1000 parameters into the .dat file. 
Now I'd want the process to go like this: 
 - Scripts start and execute at the same time; 
 - Script1 uses the first 100 parameters, script2 the next 100 and so on;

My question is simple: does the controller manage everything or do I have to set something (like "start from line:") into the script in Vugen to make things go this way?!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the unique and block size only apply across the same group and script.  I propose the following options:

- Unique data file per script/user
- Virtual Table server as the source for your parameter data. Have each user/script pull from a queue which then ensures that no matter the order of execution that any particular set of data is used once and only once by any user.   If you need specific blocks of data in particular conditions then you could populate distinct queues as well.
- If you go the "start from line" then you will have to set each script uniquely.  You will also need to manage directly the number of iterations in the test and exit before you cross into the next block reserved for others.

The easiest path is simply to use a distinct data file for each user